# how to use a token on link (<li>bla bla</li>) in struts2 without hidden form?

Tags: forms, hyperlink, struts2, token

I use this link to download file from server and I have more than one link on a single page

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit and elaborate your question so that other people here in StackOverflow can help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: A token on a link? You mean... you want to render a link with parameters?